# Ubuntu14 + VmWare + Netbeams + Cakephp conection trouble

Tags: php, ubuntu, cakephp, vmware, lamp

I am trying to use a VMWare machine with Ubuntu.

I have already installed all the LAMP stack.

I have trouble making a connection between NetBeans and my CakePHP project on the virtual machine. Is there a guide I should refer to?

Also my CakePHP project looks to be wrong. It is not changing any CSS.
http://prntscr.com/dl5gqj

Comment: the problem with the css was the mod rewrite of the apache...